# String tokenizing with arbitrary token count in C

Tags: c, strings

I am building a small program for input handling so I can conveniently parse lines and tokenize strings. The token handling works right now but I have to malloc a lot in the main() to make it work. Sadly I can not malloc everything at once because then the strings inside will have NULL pointers. Maybe someone more experienced with C can help me improve this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_tokens(char *line, char **tokens, size_t number_of_tokens) {

    // Make a copy of line to prevent it from being changed
    char *copy = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
    if (copy == NULL) {
        perror("Could not allocate memory!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy(copy, line);

    char *delimiter = " ";
    char *token = strtok(copy, delimiter);
    if (token) {
        strcpy(*tokens, token);
        size_t tokens_found = 1;
        while ((token = strtok(NULL, delimiter)) && tokens_found < number_of_tokens) {
            strcpy(*(tokens + tokens_found), token);
            ++tokens_found;
        }
    } else {
        printf("No tokens found! The supplied string was empty.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    free(copy);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main() {

    // this will also be the buffer length for the tokens
    size_t line_length = 10;
    char line[line_length];
    get_line(line, line_length);
    // Above function works just as the name implies

    size_t tokens_wanted = 2;
    char **tokens = malloc(tokens_wanted * sizeof(char**));
    for (size_t j = 0; j < tokens_wanted; ++j) {
        tokens[j] = malloc(sizeof(char) * line_length);
    }

    get_tokens(line, tokens, tokens_wanted);

    // process the tokens
    // free the elements of tokens

    free(tokens);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see some things that I think could help you improve your code.

### Use the required `#include`s

The code uses `malloc` which means that it should `#include <stdlib.h>`.  It also uses `strtok` which is in `string.h`.

### Don't leak memory

This code calls `malloc` several places but doesn't match each one with a call to `free`.  This means that the routines are leaking memory. Specifically, just before the call to `free(tokens);` in `main`, you need to also free the individually allocated memory:

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < tokens_wanted; ++j) {
   free(tokens[j]);
}
```

### Use `const` where practical

The comment about making a copy of `line` to prevent it from being changed suggests that it should be declared `const` in the parameter list:

```
int get_tokens(const char *line, char **tokens, size_t number_of_tokens) {
```

Also, the `delimiter` string should also be `const` and probably also `static`.

### Consider a different interface

In the current code the return value of `get_tokens` isn't used.  It also prints and exits the program in some circumstances.  Instead, I'd advice changing the interface in a couple of ways.  First, I'd recommend that the caller make a copy of the string if necessary.  This makes the code cleaner and simpler and allows the caller to perhaps do something other than simply abruptly halting the program if an empty string is found.  Second, I'd suggest that because `strtok` operates by modifying the passed string, there really isn't a need to allocate more memory and copy.  Instead, I'd recommend that the pointers returned can simply point to the passed string.  The much-simplified version might look like this:

```
void get_tokens(char *line, char **tokens, size_t number_of_tokens) {
    static const char *delimiter = " ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_tokens; ++i) {
        tokens[i] = strtok(line, delimiter);
        line = NULL;
    }
}
```

This works nicely and is much simpler.  If fewer than the requested number of tokens is found, the remaining `tokens` pointers are set to `NULL`. The calling function might look like this:

```
int main() {
    const size_t line_length = 100;
    char line[line_length];
    get_line(line, line_length);

    size_t tokens_wanted = 2;
    char **tokens = malloc(tokens_wanted * sizeof(char**));
    if (tokens == NULL) {
        perror("out of memory!");
        return 1;
    }
    get_tokens(line, tokens, tokens_wanted);
    for (size_t i=0; i < tokens_wanted; ++i) {
        printf("token[%lu] = \"%s\"\n", i, tokens[i]);
    }
    free(tokens);
}
```

### Omit `return 0`

When a C or C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no need to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

**Note:** when I make this suggestion, it's almost invariably followed by one of two kinds of comments:  "I didn't know that." or "That's bad advice!"  My rationale is that it's safe and useful to rely on compiler behavior explicitly supported by the standard.  For C, since C99; see ISO/IEC 9899:1999 section 5.1.2.2.3:

> [...] a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.

For C++, since the first standard in 1998; see ISO/IEC 14882:1998 section 3.6.1:

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

All versions of both standards since then (C99 and C++98) have maintained the same idea.  We rely on automatically generated member functions in C++, and few people write explicit `return;` statements at the end of a `void` function.  Reasons against omitting seem to boil down to ["it looks weird"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581993/what-the-reasons-for-against-returning-0-from-main-in-iso-c/2582015#2582015).  If, like me, you're curious about the rationale for the change to the C standard [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394171/what-was-the-rationale-for-making-return-0-at-the-end-of-main-optional).  Also note that in the early 1990s this was considered "sloppy practice" because it was undefined behavior (although widely supported) at the time.

So I advocate omitting it; others disagree (often vehemently!)  In any case, if you encounter code that omits it, you'll know that it's explicitly supported by the standard and you'll know what it means.

Comment: Why have the caller make a copy? Would it not be better to expect the caller assumes that non-target parameters should remain intact?

Comment: The advantage to having the caller make a copy are many.  First, as with the `main` code I showed, it might be avoided entirely.  Second, if there are any problems with allocating memory for the copy, they can be handled appropriately to the specific situation instead of always and invariably terminating the program.

Comment: I see one problem: In your solution the caller has to check if the tokens are NULL. Would it not be better just to return EXIT_FAILURE if the token count doesn't match so the caller can f.ex. `continue` in an input loop?

Comment: The code I posted requires no such check.  If the circumstance in which you're using it does, I'd recommend simply adding a `bool` return value that indicates whether the required number of arguments were parsed.

Comment: I just mean when you supply just one string instead of 2, the caller will get a SIGSEGV. So he has to check for all tokens whether they exist before he can use them.

Comment: The original code did no such check and neither does this rewritten code. It's not too different from requiring that the destination pointer for a `strcpy` must be big enough to hold the result.  If you want more security there, the way I'd do it would be to eliminate the function entirely and simply use `strtok` in a loop.